# I need help with these geode like rocks

Tags: rocks, minerals, fossils, crystals, geodesy

I found these rocks in my pasture and was excited because I thought I had found some geodes.  The rocks were in a sandy bank and looked like eggs sticking out of the bank.  I am located in Ness County Kansas.
[image: rough rock]

This is what they looked like after I opened them.  There are no crystals but some had a round ball in  the center.  Others were just empty centers.
[image]

Comment: Hi Michelle, Welcome to SE. What is your question here?

Comment: Could you please add some pictures, which are not out of focus?

Comment: Please [complete the missing information](https://earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com/a/125/6).

Answer (score 1):

Hi:  Your rocks are not geodes but likely concretions.  The wiki article even mentions concretions from Kansas though the concretions described don't to me fit what I see in the images.  Better pictures and more description about the rocks would lead to better identification.  See [Better rock ID requests](https://earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124/a-guide-for-asking-identify-this-rock-questions)

[Wiki's Concretion Page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concretion)